# My pc reboot randomly, even in recovery console

Tags: windows

I've got a tricky problem due to some hardware issue. I had some issues with my previous ssd but I bought a new one and made an image.

Here is my problem: when I'm in Windows, it randomly restart. In the event log I've got an empty crash event that doesn't really help.

After that I made a windows USB stick in order to run from another drive. When I go in the recovery console and type chkdsk on my windows 10 disk with the options /F /R, at some point my PC restart. I retried 3 times.

So I'm wondering if someone can point me to some ideas on what to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random reboots may mean high temparature and alarm-reboot/halt. Is your PC clean (no dust in all the fans) and well cooled?

Comment: I did some major cleanup when I swapped my hard drive. I did check the temperature in my bios and everything seems nice. I even unplugged/replugged my cable in case I unintentionally pulled a cable. But I'll try to open the case again and check more carefully.

Comment: I'll give you the answer. I did dust again all the parts and replug them afterward. Seems better so far,